iOS Swift APP, Microphone audio data collected using Audiokit cannot be recognized by Microsoft ASR
I'm developing an iOS Swift APP, integrating the AudioKit SDK, and using AudioKit to successfully collect real-time audio data from the microphone. The AVAudioPCMBuffer information obtained is
["AVLinearPCMIsNonInterleaved": 1, "AVChannelLayoutKey": <02006500 00000000 00000000>, "AVFormatIDKey": 1819304813, "AVLinearPCMBitDepthKey": 32, "AVSampleRateKey": 44100, "AVLinearPCMIsBigEndianKey": 0, "AVNumberOfChannelsKey": 2, "AVLinearPCMIsFloatKey": 1], 

then I processed it, expecting to convert the audio data into 16K mono data, I should have succeeded, and then I tried to pass this data to the Microsoft Speech Service SDK for ASR, but it doesn't seem to be recognized, and there is no text output. I need help, what should I do?
This is how I convert AVAudioPCMBuffer data into ASR data：
enter image description here
I hope to get the correct method to handle AVAudioPCMBuffer data and can be recognized by Microsoft ASR.

You could try to listen to your PCMBuffer using .audition() scattered in your code. You'll find out if the microfone actually has captured anything and if you're sending proper audio to the ASR.  https://github.com/AudioKit/AudioKit/blob/main/Sources/AudioKit/Internals/Utilities/AVAudioPCMBuffer+audition.swift
